# GitHub Actions - How to use environment variable at job level?

Tags: github-actions

I want to use environment variables at the job level. Is there a way to do it?

```
env:
  stageEnv: UAT

jobs:
  name: Upload Build
  if: ${{ env.stageEnv == 'UAT' }}
  steps:
    ....
```

I get unrecognized named-value: 'env' error. Tried $stageEnv and ${{ env.stageEnv }}

Note: It works when I access within 'steps', but would like this to be accessible at 'jobs' level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid not, but you can do like this:

```
env:
  stageEnv: UAT

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest         
    outputs:
      stageEnv: ${{ steps.init.outputs.stageEnv }}
    
    steps:        
      - name: Make environment variables global 
        id: init
        run: |
          echo "stageEnv=${{ env.stageEnv }}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

And use it in another job:

```
  upload:
    name: Upload build
    needs: build
    if: ${{ needs.build.outputs.stageEnv == 'UAT' }}
```

Note this is just an example, and I personally prefer environment variables uppercase and output variables lowercase

Comment: I was looking for it. Thanks. Just one clarification that for comparison we would need the needs.build.outputs.stageEnv == 'UAT' without curly braces.