# Value not set using $GITHUB_OUTPUT

Tags: powershell, github, github-actions

I have been previously using set-output for setting values, but we now get thee "deprecated feature" messages and I'm using $GITHUB_OUTPUT as prescribed.

I replace all instances of

```
   run: echo ::set-output name=Key::Value
```

with

```
   run: "Key=Value" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

but Key does not appear to be set.

My runner is on Windows, version 2.299.1 and the workflow is using CMD.
All calls to set-output work, and all using $GITHUB_OUTPUT do not.

Simplified action code

```
defaults:
run:
shell: cmd

jobs:
  EnvSetup:
    name: Publish Base Environment Vars
    runs-on: [self-hosted, Windows, myLabel]
    outputs:
      var_Project: ${{ steps.set-Project.outputs.Project }}
      var_Val1: ${{ steps.set-Val1.outputs.Val1 }}
      var_Val2: ${{ steps.set-Val2.outputs.Val2 }}
    steps:
      - name: Project
        id: set-Project
        run: echo ::set-output name=Project::Larry

      - name: Val1
        id: set-Val1
        run: echo "Val1=Curly" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Val2
        id: set-Val2
        run: echo "Val2=Moe" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

...

  Testing:
    name: ShowStuff
    runs-on: [self-hosted, Windows, myLabel]
    needs: [EnvSetup]
    env:
      MyProject: ${{ needs.EnvSetup.outputs.var_Project }}_ABC
    steps:
      - name: Print environment variables
        run: |
          echo "Project: ${{ needs.EnvSetup.outputs.var_Project }}" ^
          echo "MyProject: ${{ env.MyProject }}" ^
          echo "Val1: ${{ needs.EnvSetup.outputs.var_Val1 }}" ^
          echo "Val2: ${{ needs.EnvSetup.outputs.var_Val2 }}"
```

The output:

```
echo "Project: Larry"
echo "MyProject: Larry_ABC"
echo "Val1: "
echo "Val2: "
```

From everything I've seen, the way to reference the values hasn't changed, just the set.

Has anyone else tried it using CMD? I'll go to PowerShell if I have to, but that's not a small change if I can avoid it.

Comment: Syntax looks correct (compare to this example using linux / bash https://stackoverflow.com/a/74378072/3302747). So I'm guessing it's something with your runner (windows). Try something simple, like echo out Path. I'm not 100% sure of the windows syntax for cmd

Comment: @BakedInhalf, the windows runner uses PowerShell Core as the default script shell. Linux and Mac use bash. When targeting multiple platforms, it makes sense to explicitly state the `shell: cmd | pwsh | powershell | bash`.

Comment: @jessehouwing No need to specify shell every time, just add it in ```defaults: run: shell: <my-shell>``` (needs formatting)

Comment: You dropped the `echo`.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[The official docs have since been updated](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions?ref=jessehouwing.net&tool=powershell), but you need to switch to "PowerShell" at the top of the page to see all the examples in PowerShell syntax:

[image]

If you're looking for the [Windows Shell Syntax to issue GitHub Actions commands](https://jessehouwing.net/github-actions-workflow-commands-in-cmd/), I've written a blog to cover that syntax.

---

Windows runs the script task using PowerShell Core by default, not bash. So, you need to use PowerShell syntax, or set the `shell: bash` property on the script action.

```
  - name: Val2
    id: set-Val2
    run: echo "Val2=Moe" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
    shell: bash
```

When using these commands with PowerShell, make sure you redirect to `$env:GITHUB_OUTPUT`:

```
  - name: Val2
    id: set-Val2
    run: echo "Val2=Moe" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
    shell: pwsh
```

I also explicitly added `shell: pwsh` above, as the "old PowerShell" needs to be told to write UTF-8:

```
  - shell: powershell
    run: |
      "mypath" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Encoding utf8 -Append
```

When using `shell: cmd` you'd need to use `%GITHUB_OUTPUT%`, and change the codepage to Unicode:

```
@chcp 65001>nul
echo Val2=Moe >> %GITHUB_OUTPUT%
```

[image]

Comment: Blogged: https://jessehouwing.net/github-actions-workflow-commands-in-cmd/

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer for shell pwsh did not work for me I had to use the following Append method in this example in order to get it to work:

```
- name: Set color
    id: color-selector
    run: |
        "SELECTED_COLOR=green" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Append -Encoding utf8
  - name: Get color
    env:
      SELECTED_COLOR: ${{ steps.color-selector.outputs.SELECTED_COLOR }}
    run: Write-Output "The selected color is $env:SELECTED_COLOR"
```

Comment: Are you by an chance running on a self-hosted agent? If the agent can't find PowerShell 7 installed on the agent, it falls back to Windows PowerShell 5. Be sure to do a system wide installation of PowerShell 7 and to ensure that `pwsh.exe` in the system's `PATH` environment variable. Restart the agent to ensure it re-evaluates the system environment.

Comment: When using the `-append` method, be sure to include `-Encoding utf8`, you may encounter issues otherwise.