# Unable to read variable from different step in github actions

Tags: environment-variables, github-actions, workflow, github-issues

I wish to read a variable `value_deploy_path` from another step but it simply prints nothing.

---

```
name: CICD_develop
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "*"

jobs:

  SETVARS:

    runs-on: 'windows-latest'

    steps:

      - name: Get env data from web.SetParameters.xml

        id: retrivevalue

        env:
          STORE_SERVER: ${{ env.storeserver }}

        run: |

          $xmlPath = "\\$env:STORE_SERVER\D$\Jenkins\Inventory\web.Set.xml"

          $key_deploy_path = "deploy_path"

          $value_deploy_path = (Select-Xml -Literalpath $xmlPath -XPath "//setParameter[@name='$key_deploy_path']").Node.Value
          Write-Host "The value for key '$key_deploy_path' is $value_deploy_path"
          echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=value_deploy_path;isOutput=true]$value_deploy_path"    #Set output variable
          echo "Within: ${{ steps.retrivevalue.outputs.value_deploy_path }}"

      - name: print one myvalue_deploy_path from web.SetParamters.xml

        run: |
          echo "${{ steps.retrivevalue.outputs.value_deploy_path }}"
         

      - name: print myvalue_deploy_path from web.SetParamters.xml
        run: |
          $rvalue = ${{ steps.retrivevalue.outputs.value_deploy_path }}
          Write-Host "The retrived value is: $rvalue"
```

Output:

```
The value for key '$key_deploy_path' is D:\\myfolder

Within:


The retrived value is:
```

Unfortunately, all the print does not print the value except for  `Write-Host "The value for key '$key_deploy_path' is $value_deploy_path"` I. E `D:\\myfolder`

Can you please suggest why and how can I get the value of  `value_deploy_path` in a different step?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value not set using $GITHUB\_OUTPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443940/value-not-set-using-github-output)