# Unable to grab and print the output of powershell ps1 in a different step

Tags: powershell, variables, printing, output, github-actions

I have a powershell that returns `key=value` like the below:

cat C:\Logs\getallkey.ps1

```
Write-Host "app_name=Signup-qa"
```

Here is the github actions:

```
  - name: Sample append to OUT
    id: sample
    run: |
      echo "app_name_sample=worksss" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
      
  - name: Use sample script output
    run: |
      echo "Sample Application_Name: ${{ steps.sample.outputs.app_name_sample }}"  

  - name: Run  PowerShell script
    id: run-script
    run: |
      & "C:\Logs\getallkey.ps1"
      
  - name: Assign to variable
    id: run-scriptx
    run: |
      $returnvalue=& "C:\Logs\getallkey.ps1"
      echo "$returnvalue" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
     
  - name: Use script output
    run: |
      echo "Application Name: ${{ steps.run-scriptx.outputs.app_name }}"
```

See output below:

[image]

As evident from the output, `Use sample script output` step worked when similar step `Use script output` did not print the output. The below is printed in steps `Assign to variable`

```
app_name=Signup-qa
```

However, the same is not being set and printed for step `Use script output` which I tried to by means of `echo "$returnvalue" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` which I thought should have translated to `echo "app_name=Signup-qa" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` and thus should have printed for step `Use script output` as desired output, however it does not:

```
Application Name: Signup-qa
```

I also tried the below but it too did not help.

```
  - name: Assign to variable
    id: run-scriptx
    run: |
      $returnvalue=& "C:\Logs\getallkey.ps1"
      echo "$returnvalue" >> $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

Can you please assist?

Comment: Typo: missing `app_name` while setting the output parameter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value not set using $GITHUB\_OUTPUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443940/value-not-set-using-github-output)

Comment: @Azeem how am i missing `app_name`? here -> `echo "$returnvalue" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` should translate to `echo "app_name=Signup-qa" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT` and that's how `app_name` should be set alright in the output parameter?

Comment: Here is my workflow file: https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/blob/main/.github/workflows/blank.yml. I cannot use shell `bash` and rest options I tried and mentioned in my original post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443940/value-not-set-using-github-output

Comment: I missed that. That's fine if you're using it like that. However, with default Powershell, you need to use `"$returnvalue" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Encoding utf8 -Append`.

Comment: tried the suggestion `"$returnvalue" | Out-File -FilePath $env:GITHUB_OUTPUT -Encoding utf8 -Append` here `https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/blob/main/.github/workflows/blank.yml` but the output still does not print the variable `app_name`. Output here: `https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/actions/runs/5042132396/jobs/9042458293`

Comment: @Azeem Updated my post with added sample output here https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/blob/main/.github/workflows/blank.yml. the output append seems to be working when the variable is set manually but does not work when it is returned as variable from powershell ps1 file. Can you please check /  suggest?

Comment: What is the ouptut of `echo $returnvalue`? Which command is now working? BTW, you're using a self-hosted runner.  What kind of Windows is that?

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/knowyrtech/actions_param/blob/main/.github/workflows/blank.yml#L38) not working?

Comment: @Azeem no probably becoz  it's returned by powershell. Can u please check

Comment: @Azeem yes, it's a windows 10 runner

Comment: Apparently, all those commands look fine and should work. Looks like it may be something to do with the script itself or the runner but it's not obvious. Please write a sample test script returning different strings with and without `=` and try to set those as outputs.