# Github Action - how to reference env variable in the job and step if condition

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to use an env variable in both the job and step level if condition. Whatever I do, it errors or it does not show my expected behavior. Here is my code

```
name: CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ other, stable ]
env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  STABLE_BRANCH_NAME: stable
jobs:
  job1:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise, .... ]
    container:
      image: some-image
    steps:
    - name: echo
      run: echo $BRANCH_NAME
```

if I am on a branch named stable
it prints `stable`

Then I want to add if condition. I change the job to

```
jobs:
  job1:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise, .... ]
    container:
      image: some-image
    if: env.BRANCH_NAME == env.STABLE_BRANCH_NAME
    steps:
    - name: echo
      run: echo $BRANCH_NAME
```

it fails. wrong syntax

Then I change the job if condition to `if: ${{ env.BRANCH_NAME == env.STABLE_BRANCH_NAME }}` again does not work

I need two if conditions. one on the job and one on the step level like this

```
name: CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches: [ other, stable ]
env:
  BRANCH_NAME: ${{ github.head_ref || github.ref_name }}
  STABLE_BRANCH_NAME: stable
jobs:
  job1:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, linux, enterprise, .... ]
    if: #### need help here: check the branch name is stable - This one des not work
    container:
      image: some-image
    steps:
    - name: echo
      run: echo $BRANCH_NAME
      if: ${{ env.STABLE_BRANCH_NAME != env.BRANCH_NAME }}. # This one works
```

On the step level I can do `if: ${{ env.STABLE_BRANCH_NAME != env.BRANCH_NAME }}` and it works but the same does not work on the job level

How should I do this?

Found these two

- https://github.com/actions/toolkit/issues/299
- [GitHub Actions - How to use environment variable at job level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73558652/github-actions-how-to-use-environment-variable-at-job-level)

But isn't there an easier method?

Answer (score 3):

According to [context availability](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#context-availability), the `env` context is not available with job level `if`.

The allowed contexts are:

```
jobs.<job_id>.if    github, needs, vars, inputs
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`github`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) and [`vars`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#vars-context) contexts here to achieve what you're trying to do.

Here's an example with the `github` context only:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.ref_name == 'stable' }}
```

Or, with the `vars` context after configuring `STABLE_BRANCH_NAME`:

```yaml
if: ${{ github.ref_name == vars.STABLE_BRANCH_NAME }}
```

You can use other [operators](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators) to expand the condition according to your use case.

Comment: where should I define the vars? can you propose your solution as a code snippet?

Comment: @AminBa: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-configuration-variables-for-multiple-workflows to add variables to be later used with the `vars` context.