# how to concat string in github actions if condition

Tags: github, github-actions

I have this workflow

```
name: my workflow

on:
  push:

env:
  DEVELOP_BRANCH_NAME: "main"
  RELEASE_BRANCH_NAME: "release"


jobs:
  test:
    name: test
    runs-on: [ linux ]
    if: github.ref == format('refs/heads/{0}', env.RELEASE_BRANCH_NAME)

    steps:
      - name: echo
        run: echo "Hello World"
```

the workflow syntax is not valid. How do I concat string in the if condition of a job in GitHub actions workflow?

also I tried

```
if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/'${{ env.RELEASE_BRANCH_NAME }}
```

and

```
 if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/'$RELEASE_BRANCH_NAME
```

and

```
 if: github.ref == format('refs/heads/{0}', ${{ env.RELEASE_BRANCH_NAME }})
```

and it did not work

Comment: Looks like you asked a similar question before. See above [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75844035/github-action-how-to-reference-env-variable-in-the-job-and-step-if-condition). You should always lint your workflows with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to find such issues.

Comment: @Azeem you are right as always.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your expression inside ${{  }}.

```
    if: ${{ github.ref == format('refs/heads/{0}', env.RELEASE_BRANCH_NAME) }}
```

Comment: thanks. how to declare var? ca  you provide a complete example?

Comment: You could take a look here in [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#creating-configuration-variables-for-a-repository)

Comment: what linter are you using?

Comment: When you are on the GitHub or azure DevOps repo just press `.`. And you get visual studio in web.